# Is it possible to use if..else statement in React return function()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the below snippet I want to execute if else conditional opertion in react return function.
Can anyone help?

```
render() {
        //const { accountSummaries } = this.props;
        console.log(this.props.accountSummaries)
        return (
            <div>
                <table style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                    <thead class="account-table-header">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Heading1</th>
                            <th>Heading2</th>
                            <th>Heading3</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.props.accountSummaries.map((accountDetail) => {
                            return (<tr>
                                <td class="account-name">{accountDetail.accountBasic.name}</td>
                                <td class="account-name">{accountDetail.accountBasic.id}</td>
                                if({accountDetail.status} === 'GOOD')
                                    <td class="shape"><div class="green-oval"></div></td>
                                else if({accountDetail.status} === 'BAD')
                                    <td class="shape"><div class="red-oval"></div></td>
                            </tr>)
                    })}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div >
        )
    }
```

I tried searching on various blogs but couldn't find my desired solution

Answer (score 3):

```
<div className={accountDetail.status === 'GOOD' ? "green-oval" : "red-oval"}>
```

The above would be most precise/succinct solution, in my opinion.
You don't need redundant div tags.
Also, I guessed you meant className instead of just class in react.

Comment: Thanks.. it helped me

Comment: @AayushChachan Can you accept it then. Helpful for the community reading this answer.

Answer (score 2):

if else is not allowed in return.
Use ternary operators instead.

e.g if state == true ? "Yes" : "No"

```
{accountDetail.status === 'GOOD' ? <td class="shape"><div class="green-oval"></div></td> : <td class="shape"><div class="red-oval"></div></td>}
```

This should work fine.

Comment: Thanks @kooskoos it worked

Answer (score -2):

```
                                {accountDetail.status === 'GOOD' ?
                                    <td class="shape"><div class="green-oval"></div></td>
                                : (accountDetail.status === 'BAD' &&
                                    <td class="shape"><div class="red-oval"></div></td>
                                  )}
```